# Android "Transformations.map()" for MutableStateFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

For achieving the same functionality of `Transformation.map()` on `StateFlow`, I use following code and it works fine:

```
val menuCategoryNames = _menuCategories.mapLatest { menuCategories ->
    menuCategories.map { "${it.name}" }
}.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, emptyList())
```

But it looks ugly, any way to make it more readable, more elegantly?

Answer (score 1):

I've created the following extension for such case:

```kotlin
inline fun <T, R> Flow<Iterable<T>>.mapLatestIterable(crossinline transform: (T) -> R): Flow<List<R>> =
    mapLatest { it.map(transform) }
```

You can use it like this:

```kotlin
_menuCategories
    .mapLatestIterable { "${it.name}" }
    .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, emptyList())
```